# React JS button events problem it needs to click 2 times before it works

Tags: reactjs, button, react-hooks, icons, tanstackreact-query

I have a problem with the button of my code. the data was set to Active and Completed (toggle mode). When I try to click the button to complete or make it active it needs to click 2 times even though the toast is said it was success. Sometimes it works fine but when i try to do it in another data it needs to click again in order to work. (sorry for the bad english ) :

```
const [taskState, setTaskState] = useState("Completed");

const { mutateAsync: completeTask } = useCompleteTasks();
const { mutateAsync: activeTask } = useActiveTasks();

const handleTaskToggle = async (
    taskId: number,
    action: "Completed" | "Active"
  ) => {
    try {
      if (action === "Completed") {
        await completeTask(taskId);
      } else if (action === "Active") {
        await activeTask(taskId);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error toggling task:", error);
    }
  };


<button type="button" className="hover:scale-125 transition-transform"
                          onClick={() => {
                            const newTaskState =
                              taskState === "Active" ? "Completed" : "Active";
                            setTaskState(newTaskState);
                            handleTaskToggle(task.taskId, newTaskState);
                          }}
                        >
                          {CheckCircle}
                        </button>
```

I tried to add a usestate hide function after click then a setTimeout for 3-5 seconds to unhide it to know if works refetch of data.
refactored it from mapping since it has 3 icons together with it which has a separete function as well to know maybe it affects with clicking.